# What's the difference between creating a multisite vs development and production site?

Tags: version-control, staging

Can I set up a multisite to perform the dev, production site, and eventually deployment ? Are they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are different things. Multi-site means that a single drupal codebase is used to create multiple sites. A Drupal codebase is hosted in an environment like dev, staging or production. So you could have:

local

- Multisite A
- Multisite B
- Multisite C

Dev

- Multisite A
- Multisite B
- Multisite C

Staging

- Multisite A
- Multisite B
- Multisite C

Production

- Multisite A
- Multisite B
- Multisite C